# Compatibility issue with jquery ui.autocomplete

Tags: jquery, compatibility, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery **ui.autocomplete**. This is working fine in IE 11. However, I am having compatibility issues when I run my project in Mozilla(latest) or chrome(latest). I have two problems with this.

1. How do I resolve this compatibility issue and
2. What is the best way to handle these compatibility issues? Different browsers have different compatibility issues and so even if I make my project compatible with a particular browser, it could still be non-compatible in another.

   Is not there a way to make the project compatible in all browser?

Now, the code I used to try and achieve this auto-complete feature is provided below:

```
$(function () {
$.extend($.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
    _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
        $(ul).unbind("scroll");
        var self = this;
        self._scrollMenu(ul, items);
    },
    _scrollMenu: function (ul, items) {
        var self = this;
        var maxShow = 10;
        var results = [];
        var pages = Math.ceil(items.length / maxShow);
        results = items.slice(0, maxShow);

        if (pages > 1) {
            $(ul).scroll(function () {
                if (isScrollbarBottom($(ul))) {
                    ++window.pageIndex;
                    if (window.pageIndex >= pages) return;
                    results = items.slice(window.pageIndex * maxShow, window.pageIndex * maxShow + maxShow);
                    //append item to ul
                    $.each(results, function (index, item) {
                        self._renderItem(ul, item);
                    });
                    self.menu.refresh();
                    // size and position menu
                    ul.show();
                    self._resizeMenu();
                    ul.position($.extend({
                        of: self.element
                    }, self.options.position));
                    if (self.options.autoFocus) {
                        self.menu.next(new $.Event("mouseover"));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        $.each(results, function (index, item) {
            self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
    }
});
function isScrollbarBottom(container) {
    var height = container.outerHeight();
    var scrollHeight = container[0].scrollHeight;
    var scrollTop = container.scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop >= scrollHeight - height) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
$("#txtfrom").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 0,
    delay: 0
}).focus(function () {
    //reset result list's pageindex when focus on
    window.pageIndex = 0;
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
$("#txtTo").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 0,
    delay: 0
}).focus(function () {
    //reset result list's pageindex when focus on
    window.pageIndex = 0;
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
});});
```

The compatibility issues are listed below:

- IE11 - Working Fine.
- Google Chrome - scroll bar is not visible.
- FireFox - Unable to select an item from the list.

Would someone let me know what can be done to handle this compatibility issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle? That works in IE 11 and has errors in other browsers?

Comment: Well I just tried to create a fiddle but i failed miserably. I am new to js fiddle. However, I will try again and if successful will be putting in the fiddle here.

Comment: Well, here is some [starting point](http://jsfiddle.net/qLtsm05w/1/), but it currently doesn't work anywhere (I don't know your css and html, so you should update that).

Comment: I think i have a fiddle  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qLtsm05w/2/) now. The problem is that i am unable to select a value from the dropdown. Any idea what the problem is? Kindly ignore the HideError() method.

Comment: This is because you use `_renderItem` instead of `_renderItemData`, so item data is not added to element and further in jquery ui code it cannot retrieve item data from element and thus error appears - item is undefined (see your console). But actually what is unclear is what your JS code should do? I don't see any scrolls, and if you put a breakpoint to `scroll` event handler - it never fires. That's why I asked you to include code that works in IE 11, cause your current solution doesn't seem to work anywhere.

Comment: Thats the confusing part. This same piece of code is working in the IE11. I have not done anything more than what is shown in the fiddle. However, I tried using _renderItemData and it worked in the fiddle. But this same thing wont work in firefox. I am unable to select an item. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you strongly beleive it's a bug with jquery ui and not an issue with your code, check whether this is reported [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/) already, if not, go ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried change the level of autocomplete dropdown?

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 1000;
}

.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 10000;;
}

.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```